# Правильная расстановка знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Титаны — первородные божества выбрались на свободу и мечтают расправиться с новыми олимпийцами, которые и заточили их в древнюю бездну Тартар.

Comment: Прошу лишь помочь расставить знаки препинания в данном предложении.

Comment: Расставлять знаки препинания в плохо составленном предложении — все равно что поливать засохшее дерево.

Answer (score 2):

Прежде чем обсуждать пунктуацию, следовало бы исправить смысловые и стилистические огрехи. А расставлять знаки препинания в плохо составленном предложении — все равно, что поливать засохшее дерево.

1. Титаны не являются первородными божествами. Первородный — родившийся первым, а титаны — божества второго поколения. Но можно говорить о первородных титанах — титанах первого поколения.
2. Не думаю, что у бездны вообще есть возраст (скорее всего, она вечна), поэтому словосочетание "древняя бездна" вызывает сомнение.
3. Бездна называется Тартар, но сочетание "бездна Тартар" кажется мне стилистически неудачным.
4. *Титаны*, как и *олимпийцы* пишется со строчной.
5. "Новые олимпийцы" — тоже стилистически неверно. Не олимпийцы новые, а новое поколение богов — олимпийцы.

Как вариант:

**Первородные титаны выбрались на свободу и мечтают расправиться с новым поколением богов — олимпийцами, которые и заточили их в Тартар — темную и мрачную бездну.**

Comment: *сочетание "бездна Тартар" кажется мне стилистически неудачным* — у Н.Куна встречается, но вот так: "глубочайшая бездна **Тартара**". В контексте звучит так, будто в Тартаре не одна бездна.

Comment: @grizzly Бездна одна, тут как будто поэтический стиль, что-то такое я встречал, типа *божественность Всевышнего*, *неохватность бесконечности* и т. п.